# Use the bevel-tool from python script

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I want to use the bevel-tool to add a face between two other faces. The bevel-tool should use the selected edge(s) as geometry.location  is given via a selected edge.

This is what I have

[image: This is what I have]

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

Which bevel-tool should I use?
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75a_release/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=bmesh.ops.bevel#bmesh.ops.bevel
or 
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75a_release/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=bpy.ops.mesh.bevel#bpy.ops.mesh.bevel

And how can I set a enum-value? I tried offset_type='OFFSET' but I get the error that int was expected.

Script:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
obj = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()


selected_edge = None
for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.select:
        selected_edge = edge
        print("edge", edge)


print("selected_edge", selected_edge)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') # only working in object mode
faces = bmesh.ops.bevel(bm,
                geom=[selected_edge],
                offset=0.2,
                offset_type='OFFSET',
                segments=1,
                profile=0.5,
                vertex_only=False,
                clamp_overlap=True,
                material=-1)

print("faces", faces)

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
```

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Bmesh operators use integer constants instead of string enum keys. They are defined in the C code, and there's currently no other way than to find the definition in the C code and use the found values in the Python script. You may want to define some variables to make the numbers more descriptive. See here: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_operators.h;c1506454ecb4630119ed7ce13b3f8cdfef6dcee0$122

Answer (score 3):

[image]
You can find out the answer to this in several ways. Here's what I did:

1. Use the UI tool (mark the middle edge then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel).
2. Go to the info panel (above the 3D view on the default layout), and open it up a little bit. Not always, but often, using the UI commands and operators will print out the command used in the info panel. Here we can see that the `bpy.ops.mesh.bevel` operator was used.
3. To further explore this command and its documentation, open the python console. Type in:

   `bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(`

   Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to see the autocompleted documentation for this operator. In this case:

   ```
   bevel()
   bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(
       offset_type   = 'OFFSET',
       offset        = 0,
       segments      = 1,
       profile       = 0.5,
       vertex_only   = False,
       clamp_overlap = False,
       loop_slide    = True,
       material      = -1
   )
   ```

This shows you all the parameters and their defaults, you can then experiment with other values and [search for this operator in the official docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.bevel) to review any additional information you might need.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "geom" must be a list of edges AND their vertices, compare:

[Beveling edges with varying number of segments (preferably programatically)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50437/beveling-edges-with-varying-number-of-segments-preferably-programatically).